# Agregar Nodo (Listas Enlazadas)

Tags: c++, lista, poo, estructuras-de-datos, punteros

En mi implementan de listas enlazadas al agregar a partir segundo nodo no se agrega, mientras iba buscando el error en el código vi que solo agrega el primer nodo pero a partir del segundo ya no. Intenté:

1. Llegando hasta el ultimo nodo que es un NULL donde estoy instanciando un nodo y no guarda.
2. Instanciar un nodo agregar y mediante un SETer mandar esa dirección de memoria al ultimo nodo.sgteNodo y tampoco guarda.

```
void Lista::Agregar()
{
    Nodo *aux = primerNodo;
    //Input dato
    int nuevo;
    cout << "Ingrese elemento : ";
    cin >> nuevo;
    cin.ignore();
    //Guardando dato
    if (primerNodo == NULL)
    {
        primerNodo = new Nodo(nuevo);
    }
    else
    {   //1) llegar a la ultima direccion
        //while (aux != NULL) //intentar llegando uno antes que el null
        //{
        //    aux = aux->SgteNodo();
        //}
        //aux = new Nodo(nuevo);

        //2)otra opcion es que mediante un set mandemos el nodo
        //Nodo *agregar = new Nodo(nuevo);
        //aux = Iesimo(Longitud()-1);//ir al ultimo nodo que tiene un dato
        //aux->SgteNodo(*agregar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para llegar al final de la lista no debes parar en `aux==nullptr` sino en `aux->SgteNodo()==nullptr`. El motivo es que `aux` no es más que una variable que almacena una dirección de memoria y modificar esa variable no va a afectar lo más mínimo a la lista.

```
    Nodo *aux = primerNodo;
    while (aux->SgteNodo() != nullptr)
    {
        aux = aux->SgteNodo();
    }

    // Ya tienes el último nodo localizado

    Nodo *agregar = new Nodo(nuevo);
    aux->SgteNodo(agregar);
}
```

Ojo a la última línea, en el ejemplo que tu has puesto has usado

```
aux->SgteNodo(*agregar);
```

Es como si esa función no admitiese un puntero sino un objeto por valor o por referencia ... cuidado con eso que puedes acabar haciendo copias de objetos sin querer, lo que te provocará fugas de memoria.

> de que forma podría corregir el método SgteNodo?

Tienes que repasar un poco el funcionamiento de los punteros. La función bien podría quedar así:

```
class Nodo
{
    Nodo* siguiente; // O como se llame tu variable miembro
public:
    void SgteNodo(Nodo* nodo)
    { siguiente = nodo; }

    Nodo * SgteNodo()
    { return siguiente; }
};
```

---

En cualquier caso, buena parte del problema la tiene el hecho de que estás mezclando responsabilidades.

Dado que ya tienes una clase `Lista`, la misma debería ocultar la existencia de los objetos de tipo `Nodo`. En consecuencia, únicamente `Lista` está habilitada para crear y mantener una estructura de objetos de tipo `Nodo`. Bajo esta situación, y dada la nula complejidad de los objetos de tipo `Nodo`, no hay razón para que los miembros de `Nodo` no sean todos públicos:

```
struct Nodo
{
    int dato;
    Nodo * siguiente;

    Nodo(int valor)
        : dato{valor}
        , siguiente{nullptr}
    { }
};
```

Este diseño evita una complejidad innecesaria y mantiene tu código más limpio.

Comment: El motivo por el que puse aux->SgteNodo(*agregar); fue que el método SgteNodo de Nodo no tiene ningún puntero por tanto al enviar el objeto "agregar" puede el * para enviar su valor, de que forma podría corregir el método SgteNodo?
Influye en algo que el constructor de Nodo tenga asignado NULL  y no nullptr  a sgteNodo? 
En lo que pude corregir el modulo al mostrar datos tengo comportamientos indefinidos que me lleva  a ciclos infinitos  y valores inmensos que no agregue.
Gracias por tu respuesta @Eferion me guie de algunas de tus otras respuestas saludos.

Comment: Creo que con el cambio que acabo de hacer quedan tus dudas resueltas

Answer (score 1):

No se si se buena practica, pero te recomendaria que crearas un atributo puntero de tipo nodo en tu clase que apunte al ultimo nodo insertado para ahorrarte ese ciclo, además creo que el while podría mejorar si lo colocaras como:

```
while(aux->SgteNodo() != NULL) { //Esta condición sera cierta hasta que encuentre un nodo cuya siguiente dirección apunte a NULL
     aux = aux->SgteNodo();
}
Nodo *aux2 = new Nodo(nuevo);
aux->insertarSgte(aux);
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda
:)

EDIT:
Supongamos que tenemos la siguiente clase Nodo,

```
class Nodo {
    public:
       Nodo(){};
       Nodo(int dato){
           this->dato = dato;
           this->sgte = NULL; //tambien puedes escribir nullptr lo pongo así porque es la palabra que ocupas
       }
       Nodo* SgteNodo() { return sgte;}
       int getDato() { return dato; }
       void setDato(int dato) { this->dato = dato; }
       void insertarSgte(Nodo *sgte){
           this->sgte = sgte;
       }
    //Agregamos una sobrecarga de operador ostream para imprimir nuestro nodo con mas facilidad
       ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Nodo n){ 
           return os<<n.getDato(); //Solo imprimimos el contenido del nodo
       }
    private:
       int dato;
       Nodo *sgte;
};
```

Considerando lo anterior y suponiendo que quieres mostrar el contenido de la lista, puedes tener como sugerencia lo siguiente, desconozco el nombre del método pero lo siguiente debe ir dentro de esa funcion.

```
Nodo *aux = this->primerNodo;
while(aux->SgteNodo() != NULL)
{
    //cout << aux->getDato() << endl; //Opcion A ocupas el metodo getDato de la clase nodo para mostrar el contenido
    cout << *aux << endl; //Opcion B muestras el objeto de la siguiente forma con ayuda de la sobrecarga del operador mostrada en la clase anterior
    aux = aux->SgteNodo();

}
```

Como puedes observar el funcionamiento del condicional dentro del while es revisar si el siguiente nodo no sea NULL, te recomiendo que practiques un poco más de punteros, otra cosa que me sirve mucho es que a los atributos de tu clase les crees un getter y un setter junto con el nombre del atributo, eso sirve para dos cosas, uno cuando llames un metodo de cualquier objeto ya no te preocupas como se llama el metodo, simplemente piensas "oh quiero obtener el atributo tal de este objeto" y solo llamas al metodo getAtributo() o si lo quieres cambiar con el setAtributo(), lo menciono esto porque vi que ocupaste SgteNodo() tanto para mostrar y guardar el nodo ocupas el mismo metodo, se puede pero si en un futuro quieres reciclar las clases tienes que recordar una particularidad y puedes meterte en una situacion un poco complicada, por ello haciendo eso puedes mantener las cosas un poco más simples, lo mencionado es solo una opinión y algo basado en mi poca experiencia, pero que me ha resultado útil en varios proyectos de la universidad. Exito en tu trabajo.
Nota si quieres crear un estructura más reciclable utiliza templates.

Comment: Gracias por la instrucción del while Utilizando ese código y corrigiendo algunas partes como insertar(*aux2) al momento de mostrar los elementos de array obtengo un bucle infinito, y cuando muestro o imprimo estos datos son direcciones de memoria en hexadecimal, espero tu respuesta saludos

Comment: Hola, si se cicla significa, que la condición se cumple siempre, entonces de ser así, eso implica el escenario en el que solo validez que el siguente nodo no sea nulo, pero al puntero auxiliar que puede que estes ocupando no le asignes la siguiente direccion, te muestra hexadecimal porque un puntero es una direccion de memoria, lo que deberías de checar sería si es la misma dirección. Tengo en mi github estructuras de datos programadas, entre ellas la lista simplemente enlazada, te lo paso para que te apoyes. https://github.com/blackbolt121/Listas-Doblemente-Enlazadas